# python - trying to convert messy string to JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert the below data into `JSON` using python, eg `import json`. I had actually originally thought I was receiving JSON data until I echoed it out and found the below.

Unfortunately, I receive the below data from a SOAP service so have no control of how I receive it.

Anyway, does it look like the below has any structure that could be parsed? Or will I have to go through it line by line and manually convert it? It doesnt look like anything I've seen before, even though some of the variable names look like they're XML, or were originally XML.

I'm only interested in the values of the `stopData[]` array, just over halfway down, if that simplifies things!

For the record, I tried parsing it with a JSON parser as follows, but it did not recognise it:

```
    data  = json.loads(rawData)
    data['StopData']

I also tried:    
    data = json.loads(rawData)
```

but neither worked.
Here's the data I've to work with:

```
('schema', [(schema){
   _id = "NewDataSet"
   element[] = 
      (element){
         _UseCurrentLocale = "true"
         _IsDataSet = "true"
         _MainDataTable = "StopData"
         _name = "NewDataSet"
         complexType[] = 
            (complexType){
               choice[] = 
                  (choice){
                     _maxOccurs = "unbounded"
                     _minOccurs = "0"
                     element[] = 
                        (element){
                           _name = "StopData"
                           complexType[] = 
                              (complexType){
                                 sequence[] = 
                                    (sequence){
                                       element[] = 
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:boolean"
                                             _name = "ServiceDelivery_Status"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:boolean"
                                             _name = "ServiceDelivery_MoreData"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "StopMonitoringDelivery_Version"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:boolean"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:boolean"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:string"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_VisitNumber"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:boolean"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                          (element){
                                             _type = "xs:dateTime"
                                             _name = "Timestamp"
                                             _minOccurs = "0"
                                          },
                                    },
                              },
                        },
                  },
            },
      },
 }])('diffgram', [(diffgram){
   DocumentElement[] = 
      (DocumentElement){
         StopData[] = 
            (StopData){
               _id = "StopData1"
               _rowOrder = "0"
               ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.33+00:00",
               ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef[] = 
                  "bac",
               ServiceDelivery_Status[] = 
                  "true",
               ServiceDelivery_MoreData[] = 
                  "false",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_Version[] = 
                  "1.0",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.333+00:00",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef[] = 
                  "0",
               MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.333+00:00",
               MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef[] = 
                  "02371",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef[] = 
                  "27",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef[] = 
                  "Inbound",
               FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef[] = 
                  "2013-01-21",
               FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef[] = 
                  "4215",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName[] = 
                  "77A",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef[] = 
                  "bac",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef[] = 
                  "00354",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName[] = 
                  "Ringsend Rd via Tymon Park",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored[] = 
                  "true",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion[] = 
                  "false",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef[] = 
                  "027023A:34",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef[] = 
                  "33521",
               MonitoredCall_VisitNumber[] = 
                  "39",
               MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop[] = 
                  "false",
               MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:21:00+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:20:12+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:21:00+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:20:12+00:00",
               Timestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.627+00:00",
            },
            (StopData){
               _id = "StopData2"
               _rowOrder = "1"
               ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.33+00:00",
               ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef[] = 
                  "bac",
               ServiceDelivery_Status[] = 
                  "true",
               ServiceDelivery_MoreData[] = 
                  "false",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_Version[] = 
                  "1.0",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.333+00:00",
               StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef[] = 
                  "0",
               MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.333+00:00",
               MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef[] = 
                  "02371",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef[] = 
                  "27",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef[] = 
                  "Inbound",
               FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef[] = 
                  "2013-01-21",
               FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef[] = 
                  "4061",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName[] = 
                  "77A",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef[] = 
                  "bac",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef[] = 
                  "00354",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName[] = 
                  "Ringsend Rd via Tymon Park",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored[] = 
                  "true",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion[] = 
                  "false",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef[] = 
                  "027008:34",
               MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef[] = 
                  "33204",
               MonitoredCall_VisitNumber[] = 
                  "39",
               MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop[] = 
                  "false",
               MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:44:00+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:44:00+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:44:00+00:00",
               MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T21:44:00+00:00",
               Timestamp[] = 
                  "2013-01-21T20:57:40.627+00:00",
            },
      },
 }])
```

Comment: You're right that this is clearly not JSON, so this isn't relevant this time… But in general, saying "It did not recognize it" or "neither worked" isn't very helpful; post the exception and traceback instead.

Comment: The SOAP service should be giving your the content type in the header. Can you print that out and tell us what it says? Also, you often _do_ have control over what you get, through a parameter that says what type you want (e.g., that's how many services let you choose XML vs. JSON vs. presentable HTML). Also, the SOAP service probably has some documentation (if it's public) or someone you can ask about it (if it's internal), so even if it isn't a standard notation, you can hopefully get the language definition instead of guessing at it, which will make a parser much easier to write.

Comment: have you tried json.loads(); ?  read this https://jsonweb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I fixed this by using code like this:

```
tmpData = requestoutput[1][0][0][0]
```

This showed me that the data is actually stored in a multi-dimensional array. When I put that into python, it creates an array (although when I output it [data=list], it told me it cant concatenate a string and a list).

But anyway, I can now access individual elements of data using arrays.

Cheers.